# $2d$ line equations in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry

I know in polar coordinates, a $2d$ line equation is given in the form of $$r = x \cdot \cos(\theta) + y \cdot \sin(\theta),$$ where the parameters are defined as in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

I want to derive an equation of the $2d$ line which is perpendicular to that given line and passing through a given another point (say $(x_1, y_1)$). What would be the equation of the new line?

Comment: Try $r'=-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$. Adapt $r'$ for your point to belong to the latter.

Comment: @ julien: sorry, how could i compute new r (r′)?

Comment: Plug $(x_1,y_1)$ in the new equation.

Comment: @ julien: oh,, got. thanks. :-)

Comment: Note that your equation is actually in cartesian coordinates, not polar.

Comment: @julien, care to make your comments an answer? Just to get this off the unanswered list…

Comment: @MvG You're right, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comments to the answer box.

A general equation for a line orthogonal to the one you gave is
$$
r'=-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta.
$$

Now plug $(x_1,y_1)$ in the above equation to find the (unique) value of $r'$ that make it pass through $(x_1,y_1)$.